# How do I run DBT models from a Python script or program?

Tags: python, dbt

I have a DBT project, and a python script will be grabbing data from the postgresql to produce output.

However, part of the python script will need to make the DBT run. I haven't found the library that will let me cause a DBT run from an external script, but I'm pretty sure it exists. How do I do this?

ETA: The correct answer may be to download the DBT CLI and then use python system calls to use that.... I was hoping for a library, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update: v1.5 has arrived!

With v1.5 of dbt, we get a stable and officially supported Python API for invoking dbt operations; this API has functional parity with the CLI.

From the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/programmatic-invocations):

```py
from dbt.cli.main import dbtRunner, dbtRunnerResult

# initialize
dbt = dbtRunner()

# create CLI args as a list of strings
cli_args = ["run", "--select", "tag:my_tag"]

# run the command
res: dbtRunnerResult = dbt.invoke(cli_args)

# inspect the results
for r in res.result:
    print(f"{r.node.name}: {r.status}")
```

There are some caveats about the stability of artifacts returned by `dbt.invoke`; read the docs for more details.

### Original Answer

(As of Jan 2023) There is not a public Python API for dbt, yet. It is expected in v1.5, which should be out in a couple months.

Right now, your safest option is to use the CLI. If you don't want to use `subprocess`, the CLI uses [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) now, and Click provides a [runner](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.testing.CliRunner) that you can use to invoke Click commands. It's usually used for testing, but I think it would work for your use case, too. The CLI command is [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/7077c475511b4f251245b6e246b9a23bed18eed0/core/dbt/cli/main.py#L292). That would look something like:

```py
from click.testing import CliRunner
from dbt.cli.main import run

dbt_runner = CliRunner()
dbt_runner.invoke(run, args="-s my_model")
```

You could also invoke dbt the way they do in the test suite, using [`run_dbt`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/1e35339389ded85631128b66f57c62ca60649c88/core/dbt/tests/util.py#L63).

Comment: "(As of Jan 2023) There is not a public Python API for dbt, yet. It is expected in v1.5, which should be out in a couple months."

Can you provide a source for this? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/milestone/82

Comment: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/6356#issuecomment-1466790980

Comment: Answer has been updated to reflect the new state of the art in v1.5

Comment: How do I invoke a dbt command from a file in a different directory than the dbt project?

Comment: `dbt_runner.invoke(["run", "--project-dir", "/path/to/dir"])` should work just fine.

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch @tconbeer you may also have to specify the `--profiles-dir` arg

Comment: @tconbeer - have you had success with programmatically invoking `run-operation` (`["run-operation", "my_macro", "--args", f"""{{"param1": "{x}"}}"""]`) and retrieving the return value? The `dbtRunnerResult` doesn't have anything relevant to the return value of the `macro`. Thank you.